# How to download a drive.google.com/file using linux cli

Tags: linux, file, terminal, download, drive

I have been trying to download a file from a `drive.google.com/file/d/FILEID/view?usp=sharing` link with wget, but it can't seem to work. I just get a very long text file with html code in it.
I have tried using the --no-cookies option, but it doesn't work either.
It looks like wget gets stuck at the Google authentification page and I don't know what to do to "bypass" it.
I hope I made everything clear, I have been looking at a lot of problems like this one on forums but haven't found a solution yet. Can you please help me ?
Thank you,
Best regards,
Ethan

I tried using `wget --no-cookies 'drive.google.com/file/FILEID/view?usp=sharing'`
I also tried it without the `--no-cookies`
I expected to download the file that was shared (it is a .tar file)
Instead it created a very long text file named 'view?usp=shar'